# Not Getting Response from Java Servlet into Cardova/Phonegap project For Android

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to send first name and last name to java servelet. Request is accepted by servelet but response not showing back on application. I have searched for the internet that config.xml file line  should be changed.
I have tried following combinations on it but no use.

```
My targer URL: http://myip:8081/MiddleWareUsman/androidServlet
<access origin="http://myip*" />
<access origin="http://myip:8081/MiddleWareUsman/androidServlet" />
<access origin="http://myip:8081" />
```

I have tried alot. But no use. Please help if anybody knows this issue.
I am attaching javascript button event and logs

```
buttonClick: function(evt) {
    var input1=this.byId("Input1");
        var input2=this.byId("Input2");
        var label=this.byId("Label1");

    $.ajax({                
    url : "http://myip:8081/MiddleWareUsman/androidServlet",
    type : "post",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    data : {
            "fname" : input1.getValue(),
            "lname" : input2.getValue()

            },
    success : function(data) {
label.setText("Respose from server is"+ data)

    }
    });


    }
});
```

Logs:

```
03-13 16:46:23.501: E/Trace(19435): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-13 16:46:40.499: E/chromium(19435): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [0313/164640:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App com.mycompany.serveletcallusman isn't supported.
03-13 16:46:40.499: E/chromium(19435): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [0313/164640:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App com.mycompany.serveletcallusman isn't supported.
03-13 16:46:40.789: E/Web Console(19435): Uncaught ReferenceError: usmanshaffi is not defined at http://myip:8081/MiddleWareUsman/androidServlet?callback=jQuery17102445647087879479_1394711186603&fname=usman&lname=shaffi&_=1394711200355:1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<access origin="*" />
```

remove all these lines

```
<access origin="http://myip*" />
<access origin="http://myip:8081/MiddleWareUsman/androidServlet" />
<access origin="http://myip:8081" />
```

Make sure you add into config.xml inside xml folder, not the outside one.

[image]

Comment: <access origin="*" /> i have tried this too..but no use